# How to get sip messages on during call on android?

Tags: android, webrtc, pjsip

I want to get and read sip info messages on during call. I sent other side to sip info message and I saw on logcat but I dont get the message on code. I use the pjsip.

How to get sip info messages on during call?

Thanks.

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1):

you will require. onCallTsxState call back function from call class to listen to Sip message shared during the call. It took quite some time for me to figure out and hopefully it could help some once else ,if its too late for you.

```
  @Override
    public void onCallTsxState(OnCallTsxStateParam prm) {
    
    if (eventBody.getTsxState().getType() == (pjsip_event_id_e.PJSIP_EVENT_RX_MSG)) {
          SipRxData rdata = eventBody.getTsxState().getSrc().getRdata();
    
    //technically here in messageBuffer I am storing all header file info shared during the call 
          String messageBuffer = rdata.getWholeMsg();
          Log.e("bingo", String.valueOf(messageBuffer));
    // in my case in my case I am  check presences of info message : Connection Established every time new header message is send 
       if(messageBuffer.contains("Connection established")){
          Log.e("bingo", "bingo established");
    
          try {
    
              //perform what ever you want to do here when you receive info message
       
    
                }
             });
```