# How to read specific content(sip info request ) from PJSIP header files?

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

How can i read below message: connection established while making call in pjsip pjsua2 for android app.

> 

```
 2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY
2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: Supported: timer, path, replaces
2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: Content-Type: text/plain
2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: Content-Length: 24
2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: Connection established
2021-10-25 17:12:37.468 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: --end msg--
2021-10-25 17:12:37.469 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 17:12:37.469        tsx0x7503bcd0a8  ..Request msg INFO/cseq=43033586 (rdata0x7503bed318) was unhandled by dialog usages, sending 500 response
2021-10-25 17:12:37.470 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 17:12:37.470           pjsua_core.c  ....TX 468 bytes Response msg 500/INFO/cseq=43033586 (tdta0x7503c5a0a8) to TLS 35.156.17.231:5061:
2021-10-25 17:12:37.471 19483-19641/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: SIP/2.0 500 Unhandled by dialog usages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will require. onCallTsxState call back function from call class to listen to Sip message shared during the call. I have already answered here at below link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69735690/8795652)